# Allow end clients to edit Like button URL and Open Graph tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps

trying to improve my question asking etiquette, so I'll state my aim, ask my question, then follow up with what research I have done.

**Aim**: we are building a new bolt-on subsite to give to possibly many end clients to place on their server, so their site may be built on Windows or Unix. With this in mind, we have opted with building it in HTML and Javascript. The bolt on will produce a recommendation for a product after a series of questions and the user will have the opportunity to Like the recommendation to Facebook.

**Question**: If the correct meta og tags in the code were indicated to an end client, could they replace the domain in the og:URL?

**Research**: I have looked for a similar problem on this site, but not found anything related - apart from [What's the difference between the Like button with or without Open Graph META tags?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8582223/whats-the-difference-between-the-like-button-with-or-without-open-graph-meta-ta) I have created a Test App and have linked it to my test url on my server and understand that when the Like is clicked, Facebook reloads the page and gathers the og meta data. I have used this knowledge to implement a random product generator using JQuery to write out a different og:description to test out the idea that the end user can get any one of many recommended products that they can Like on the same end URL (eg http://www.domain.com/yourRecommendedProduct.html).

I also understand that if the URL is changed on my test server and I call my app using the fb:app_id, the app uses the Website url to call my original URL and Likes the old og:description.

In the subsite documentation, I hope to be able to tell the end clients that they can edit og:url for their domain, og:image for their company logo - og:description will be generated on the fly using Javascript through a series of questions.

But from what I have seen, if you edit the og:url, it won't match the one in the app.

Can you implement the FB Like button using the Open Graph tags whilst NOT linking to a FB app? Just read something else that appeared on the Similar Questions pane that seemed to say that the Open Graph thing was to create a link between a single page and create a Page within Facebook - which it seems is beyond what I require. So I've probably missed a step somewhere in just creating a silly simple Like button with Meta og data??

many thanks for any pointers or help
Frank

Comment: I've also hit another wall - I've just found out that the Like button data is gather at page load and even though I can adjust the og meta tags using jQuery the original data has already been used to generate the hidden Like box that appears. So it seems I can only generate og property meta tags using a server side language; unless I'm missing something obvious? (been a long day, massive toothache and no dentist = brain not working correctly...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=71904

This answers all my questions. How to create a Like button easily and simply without using an App - the Official FB documentation doesn't drill down from a beginners to advanced level of tutorials which IMHO it should - might lead to less questions on here.

Also any newbies here reading this; once you've updated your code and sent to server, send the link through to the FB Debugger as it seems to refresh the content at FB.

Also use "FB Insights" to find out your fb:Admins number.

Thanks for help DMCS.

Comment: This answered my question "Can you instruct an end client to edit a Like button?" because it shows how to set up the Like button and that you don't need an app_id to have one on your page; therefore you can have the same code on different static pages but just tweak the URL, image, description etc for each page/client.

Comment: The link you've posted is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out Facebook's linter does not run JavaScript.

So you've gotta get your web-server to spit out the correct og tags at the request of the linter.  So the URL you use in the Like code is going to be crucial.  You'll need a way for that URL to be unique and also for the web-server to know what og tags to render out for it.

So your solution is going to either know the unique urls of each product, or your solution is going to need to include server side code that produces unique content for each product (maybe something like /getProduct.php?id=123 or REST like /products/123/).

Comment: Cheers DMCs - is there ANY way it can be done client side; I want to explore this completely before going serverside. I read somewhere that when you "Like", facebook reloads the page to scrape the <meta> data? I've looked at the <iframe> version which has a back reference to the site url - does this conduct a reload? It's funny that dynamically writing out the <meta> tags server side is so easy but once those headers have been sent, that's it... am still experimenting client side, so hopefully something will turn up.

Comment: I've just checked with another project developer - luckily the product list is only going to be either 9 or 12 items. So you answer the questions and then get Product1, 2, 3 etc recommended. So having 9~12 unique urls could be ok - eg domain.com/recommendedProduct1.html and build in the property tags hardcoded for each item. That would work; I was just trying to be code efficient in having one end result page to which the results were written (using localStorage). Would it still work to tell end clients to replace domain.com/product1.html with their domain in the iframe?

Comment: You can use one page to be the "unique" url for each.  If your project developer doesn't know how to do the last paragraph in my original answer, then it's time to fire them and get a project developer who knows how to code.  It's a super basic thing, nothing magical.  They should know how to do it if you're paying them the big bucks to be a project dev.

Comment: LOL do I hasten to add I am the main developer on this project... probably "project developer" should have been "project planner"... but I understand what you mean about using something like php for a single page that mysql writes to. IF I use just html to create 10~12 static pages, will I get stuck if I tell the client to change the domain in og:image or og:url etc to show their logo or company name because the app this Like links to has a Site URL pointing at my test server. So ultimately, can I implement the Like button without back reference to an app_id?

Comment: As a test, I have set up a php page with a series of arrays with random product data in and then echo'ed out that random data firstly to the meta tags and then to the <body> so I can see what has been generated. I click Like, it all works (Logo, product description, made up client name, link to client site) EXCEPT its refreshed content? When you click on Like, does the page get reloaded and the data re-scraped or something? This is just an academic question - in deployment I wont be using random data; but it does seem when Like is clicked, the page is reloaded - is this true?

Comment: The page will only be reloaded upon like when the page/application is in a fan page tab. Otherwise on a normal web page where there is a like button, it should not cause a page refresh.  Without seeing your code it's kinda hard to answer.  Please start a different question for this as it is different than the one you originally asked.